How to cast a macro using the streaming operator

I have Systemverilog macros for endianess-aware parsing of unpacked data:

The purpose of this macro is to take any BYTE_WIDTH Bytes from an BYTE_OFFSET offset at a Byte array, and pack them into a vector.


I've been running an older Modelsim version with it without issue.
Recently I updated the simulator to an updated version of Questa Base, and started receiving this warning, for files calling that macro, although the functionality is correct.
Is there a proper way to write this as a macro?
Self Contained Example of use (file example.sv):
`define PARSE_LITTLE_ENDIAN(TARGET, SOURCE, BYTE_OFFSET, BYTE_WIDTH) \
TARGET = $size(TARGET)'({<<8{SOURCE[BYTE_OFFSET +: BYTE_WIDTH]}})

`define PARSE_BIG_ENDIAN(TARGET, SOURCE, BYTE_OFFSET, BYTE_WIDTH) \
TARGET = $size(TARGET)'({>>8{SOURCE[BYTE_OFFSET +: BYTE_WIDTH]}})

class my_parser;

    bit  [64-1:0] body_len;
    logic[8-1:0]  frame_buffer[];

    function void call_macro();

        this.frame_buffer = new[10];

        for (int byte_idx = 0; byte_idx < this.frame_buffer.size(); byte_idx++)
        begin
          this.frame_buffer[byte_idx] = $urandom();
        end

        `PARSE_LITTLE_ENDIAN(this.body_len, this.frame_buffer, 2, 8);
        `PARSE_BIG_ENDIAN(this.body_len, this.frame_buffer, 2, 8);

    endfunction

endclass

Compilation result:
vlog -sv example.sv 
Questa Base Edition-64 vlog 2024.1 Compiler 2024.02 Feb  1 2024
Start time: 11:26:42 on Apr 10,2024
vlog -sv example.sv 
-- Compiling package example_sv_unit
** Warning: example.sv(21): (vlog-2960) Streaming concatenation shall not be used as an operand in an expression without first casting it to a bit-stream type.
** Warning: example.sv(22): (vlog-2960) Streaming concatenation shall not be used as an operand in an expression without first casting it to a bit-stream type.

Top level modules:
        --none--
End time: 11:26:42 on Apr 10,2024, Elapsed time: 0:00:00
Errors: 0, Warnings: 2

Note: The code simulates well and also builds well into a Xilinx FPGA using Vivado.
The following doesn't work:
$cast(TARGET,{<<BYTE{SOURCE[BYTE_OFFSET +: BYTE_WIDTH]}}) gives the same warning.
And
TARGET = $size(TARGET)'($type(TARGET)'({<<BYTE{SOURCE[BYTE_OFFSET +: BYTE_WIDTH]}}))
or
TARGET = $type(TARGET)'($size(TARGET)'({<<BYTE{SOURCE[BYTE_OFFSET +: BYTE_WIDTH]}}))
error out.

You need to give us an example that shows all the data types involved and what you want the results to be.

Thanks Dave, added. Hope the information is complete now.

Not enough. Need an example with results. minimal, complete reproducible examples. Focus on what the code you want the macro to produce, not the macro.

Better now? it's self contained.

It works even with the macros. I'm just trying to cleanup the new warnings.

Yes, the macros were just the way I did it previously. I now changed the simulator to Questa and got the warnings. To clarify - when written explicitly, or when using the macro, no warnings in Modelsim DE 2022.4, but the warnings appear in Questa.

I'm not sure why you are getting the error message, but the cast to size is unnecessary with the code you show and removing it gets rid of the warning message.
Here is what I mean by complete runnable example:
`define PARSE_LITTLE_ENDIAN(TARGET, SOURCE, BYTE_OFFSET, BYTE_WIDTH) \
TARGET    = {<<8{SOURCE[BYTE_OFFSET +: BYTE_WIDTH]}}
`define PARSE_BIG_ENDIAN(TARGET, SOURCE, BYTE_OFFSET, BYTE_WIDTH) \
  TARGET  = {>>8{SOURCE[BYTE_OFFSET +: BYTE_WIDTH]}}

class my_parser;
    bit  [64-1:0] body_len;
    logic[8-1:0]  frame_buffer[];
    function void call_macro();
       this.frame_buffer = new[10];
       void'(randomize(frame_buffer));
       $displayh("%p",frame_buffer);
        `PARSE_LITTLE_ENDIAN(this.body_len, this.frame_buffer, 2, 8);
       $displayh(body_len);
        `PARSE_BIG_ENDIAN(this.body_len, this.frame_buffer, 2, 8);
       $displayh(body_len);
    endfunction
endclass

module top;
   my_parser p  = new;

   initial p.call_macro();
endmodule


Thanks! (BTW my tool license does not support the randomize function but I already knew that)
